# Batch script: extract text after/before last/first occurrence of characters and store it in array

Tags: arrays, string, batch-file, text, windows-10

Suppose I have the following content in my file under "%userprofile%\~.txt":

```
Monitor: Generic PnP Monitor
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1
Adapter: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
(1920 x 1080 x 32 bpp) 60Hz default up, attached (-1920,0)

Monitor: Generic PnP Monitor
Device: \\.\DISPLAY4
Adapter: NVIDIA Quadro P2000
(1280 x 1024 x 32 bpp) 60Hz default up, attached (1920,0)

Monitor: Generic PnP Monitor
Device: \\.\DISPLAY8
Adapter: DisplayLink USB Device
(1920 x 1080 x 32 bpp) 60Hz default up, attached, primary (0,0)
```

The number of text blocks can vary.

What I want to get is the first of the two coordinates appearing on the last line of each block, so according to the example, the result should be:

```
-1920
1920
0
```

To do so in a batch script, I first analyze the file by an initial for loop, that retrieves the lines containing the string "default up, attached".

Then for each retrieved string, I search for the text after the last occurrence of `(`.

From the previous results, I search for the text before the first occurrence of `,`.

I found a solution that works outside the for loop (see lines marked with `**` below), but I want these lines to be inside the loop. I tried lines marked with `*` below but the script exits and I have no clue what the error is. Hopefully a trivial missing piece. Please bear with my low batch scripting knowledge.

My script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Cnt=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('findstr "default up, attached" "%userprofile%\~.txt"') DO (
  set /a Cnt+=1
  set result=%%a
  for %%b in ("%result:(=" "%") do set "result=%%~b"                          <= * THESE LINES DON'T WORK!!!
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%c in ("%result%") do set "result=%%~c"         <= * THESE LINES DON'T WORK!!!
  call Set Monitors[%%Cnt%%]=!result!
)
for %%b in ("%Monitors[1]:(=" "%") do set "Monitors[1]=%%~b"                  <= ** THESE LINES WORK
for %%b in ("%Monitors[2]:(=" "%") do set "Monitors[2]=%%~b"                  <= ** THESE LINES WORK
for %%b in ("%Monitors[3]:(=" "%") do set "Monitors[3]=%%~b"                  <= ** THESE LINES WORK
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%c in ("%Monitors[1]%") do set "Monitors[1]=%%~c" <= ** THESE LINES WORK
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%c in ("%Monitors[2]%") do set "Monitors[2]=%%~c" <= ** THESE LINES WORK
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%c in ("%Monitors[3]%") do set "Monitors[3]=%%~c" <= ** THESE LINES WORK
echo %Monitors[1]%
echo %Monitors[2]%
echo %Monitors[3]%
pause
```

Comment: You have a variable expansion problem with the first two lines you have marked. Any variable created or changed inside a parenthesized code block must use delayed expansion.  Which means you use exclamation points with the variable instead of percent symbols.

Comment: Regardless I would just use the left and right parentheses as delimiters and use the corresponding token which would be 3.  Then put it through another FOR /F command an use the comma as the delimiter.

Comment: @Squashman can you help me on how would those lines look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to make use of powershell regex to do this:

```bat
@Echo off

:# Replace with actual filename
 Set "File=%~dp0in.txt"
 Set "Content=\(-?\d+,\d+\)$"
 Set "Prefix=^.*?,+ \w+ \("
 Set "Suffix=,\d*\)"

:# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1

Set "[i]=1"
For /f "Delims=" %%G in ('
 powershell -nologo -noprofile -c ^
 "(GC "%File%") -match '%Content%' | ForEach {"$_" -replace '%Prefix%' -replace '%Suffix%'}
')Do Call Set /A "[i]+=1","Monitor[%%[i]%%]=%%G"

 Set Monitor[

Goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parentheses and the comma as a delimiter to get the required value. Because you have extra commas in one of your input lines this will require two nested `FOR` commands. The first `FOR` will split it up by the parentheses and will give you everything between the second set of parentheses.  Then put that output into another `FOR` command to split the value at the comma.

```
@echo off
REM use the parentheses as a delimiter
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=()" %%G IN ('findstr "default up, attached" "file.txt"') DO (
    REM USE the comma as a delimiter for the final split up of the variable.
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1 delims=," %%H IN ("%%~G") DO ECHO %%~H
)
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice. I like the regexp solution from @T3RR0R a tad bit more, since I imagine the content of the lines could change in the future.